# Join and SUM in Laravel ELoquent

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

Database Structure is as follows:

> Table: users

```
id | name | email | password
```

> Table: analytics

```
id | user_id(fk) | article_id(fk) | revenue | date | clicks
```

Now I want the list of all users with the sum of their own *revenue* from these two Tables.

What I tried is as follows:

```
$users = User::select('users*', 'analytics.*', 'SUM(analytics.revenue)')
         ->leftJoin('analytics', 'analytics.user_id', '=', 'users.id)
         ->where('analytics.date', Carbon::today()->toDateString())
         ->get();
```

But it is throwing me error.

Comment: i have not knowledge of larave, but as i seen your query you are not use group by user. after adding group by it will work

Comment: At this point, Eloquent doesn't actually add much abstraction value in my opinion and you would be better off doing a `DB::connection()->getPdo()` and writing the query by hand.

Answer (score 6):

You may try this

```
$users = User::select('users*', 'analytics.*', DB::raw('SUM(analytics.revenue) As revenue'))
         ->leftJoin('analytics', 'analytics.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
         ->where('analytics.date', Carbon::today()->toDateString())
         ->get();
```

Comment: Maybe you also want to add a `->groupBy('users.id')` statement.

Comment: when there is no data on the joined table it reduces the data by grouping the items, the items I want to display aren't showing. however `DB::raw('SUM(analytics.revenue) As revenue')` works well

Answer (score 6):

This maybe a bit late. Maybe will help someone else.

You need to include every select columns in groupBy. In your case:

```
$users = User::select('users.id', 'users.name', 'users.password', 'analytics.date', 'analytics.clicks', 'SUM(analytics.revenue) as revenue')
     ->leftJoin('analytics', 'users.id', '=', 'analytics.user_id')
     ->where('analytics.date', Carbon::today()->toDateString())
     ->groupBy('users.id', 'users.name', 'users.password', 'analytics.date', 'analytics.clicks') 
     ->get();
```

Comment: This works for me. Can you please explain why it is needed to add all columns to group by?

Answer (score 4):

```
$users = User::select(\DB::raw('users.*, SUM(analytics.revenue) as revenue'))
         ->leftJoin('analytics', 'analytics.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
         ->groupBy('users.id')
         ->get();
```